# Cannot connect to my Cassandra

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, connection-refused

My Cassandra used to work with no problems.

I was able to connect with no problems but now for some reason it doesn't work anymore.

```
[default@unknown] connect localhost/9160;
Exception connecting to localhost/9160. Reason: Connection refused.
```

and

```
root# ./bin/cassandra-cli -host localhost -port 9160
Exception connecting to localhost/9160. Reason: Connection refused.
```

I am on Linux Ubuntu Server.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have your verified that the cassandra daemon is actually running? Find anything informative in its log files?

Comment: Did you check to see if Cassandra is listening on port 9160: `lsof -i :9160`, `netstat -nl | grep 9160`, ...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have already suggested make sure your cassandra instance is running

```
ps axu | grep cassandra
```

If the output tells you that it is running you can check what ports it is listening on:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep -i listen | grep <pid>
```

where  is the process id of your cassandra instance which you can get from the output of the first command.

You are interested to find the port 9160 in the output of this command. You will know from this what address it is listening on (if for some reason it is no longer a localhost).

If for some reason you can't find 9160 port in the list of the listening sockets then you might want to check your cassandra.yaml config file (search for rpc_port). You will also find there the address where thrift binds to to listen for clients on.

Comment: i'm using first command 6335  0.0  0.0  14228   968 pts/6    S+   17:13   0:00 grep --color=auto cassandra

Comment: second command netstat -tulpn | grep -i listen | grep 6335 but my issue is not resloved

Comment: using cqlsh command Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Answer (score 4):

By default Thrift is not up, you have to start it with

```
nodetool enablethrift
```

Comment: Can you add detail on how this answers the question or improves on the accepted answer?

Comment: We  can use netstat -atn to check whether port 9160 is active or not. As  given by Perry Cox we can execute nodetool enablethrift to enable Thrift communication. It was veryuseful for me to run kairosdb.