# Postfix can't connect to MariaDB on 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, mysql, postfix

*(Yes, [this question seems very similar](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message), but I understand why I get the message. What I don't get, and can't find any palpable information about on my own, is what to do about it. So here I am.)*

---

I am trying to set up Postfix and Dovecot on my VPS, deciding to go the MySQL-route with MariaDB. Following [this guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql), which seems pretty okay.

Got as far as to test the DB config files with postmap, when the server simply refused connection. This is the error message I get;

```
postmap: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")
postmap: fatal: table mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf: query error: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

MariaDB's config file is set up to bind with 127.0.0.1, I opened 3306 for 127.0.0.1 and even tried disabling the firewall altogether without any change.

It seems that the IP and port can't be to blame then, and I assume this "Transport endpoint" must be the culprit - if that's not just another way of referring to the IP/port.

If anyone has suggestions as to what I can try to get around this, I would be incredibly grateful.

Edit: If it makes any difference, I'm using nginx as well.

Edit II:
    Results of 'service mysql status':

```
* /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 9.1 Distrib 10.1.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Server version          10.1.11-MariaDB-1~trusty-log
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 2 hours 37 min 16 sec
```

Comment: Output of systemctl mysqld status

Comment: @JacobEvans I added the output of service mysql status, which I assume does the same job. I see that it's connecting through the socket, but using localhost in the DB config for Postfix apparently is a no-go as far as all the information I've found on it is concerned. :')

Maybe I should try using the UNIX socket path as host?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: In response to your edit and as Iain suggested: Is MariaDB actually listening for TCP connections on the default port? (That's port  3306) If it is, then be aware that GRANT-ing rights for TCP connections is different from allowing access from localhost..

Comment: @HBruijn Using the command "netstat -tln" shows that nothing is indeed listening on 3306. Huh.
Guess I have to find out what GRANT-ing is about then. :)

Comment: @HBruijn Oh, I see! Or I think I do. You mean adding a record in the user table of MariaDB to let the user connect through TCP? But it's still not listening for connections though. Gotta figure it out! :)

Comment: Can you log in with mysql -h127.0.0 1

Comment: Okay, thank you for pointing me in the right direction @HBruijn! I disabled the 'skip-networking' directive in my.cnf and restarted MariaDB, and now it listens to 127.0.0.1! I was actually looking at it before too, but I thought it was only for _remote_ access, so I didn't think that's what I needed!

Comment: Looks like a config issue, or you never restarted the service. Post your configuration and what system you're using.

Comment: You're right, it was a config issue. The skip-networking directive was shutting off TCP completely, but I thought I'd open for remote access if I disabled it. Took a second look at this page, and voila!

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here, after HBruijn set me on the right path: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/

MariaDB has the skip-networking directive active as default, which stops all TCP/IP connections. After commenting it out, but leaving bind-address as is I let MariaDB listen to TCP on the default port (3306) only for local connections.

Change this in my.cnf:

```
#skip-networking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Restarted the mysql service and tested to see what ports were listened on;

```
# netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
..some records..
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Also successfully logged into MariaDB through 127.0.0.1, and everything works! Yay!

```
# mysql -u mailuser -h 127.0.0.1 -D mailserver -p
Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 49
Server version: 10.1.11-MariaDB-1~trusty-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [mailserver]>It finally works!
```