# port listening in netstat can't telnet

Tags: linux, networking, connection-refused

I'm trying to connect to port 8020 on a CentOS vm but I'm getting `telnet: connect to address <public_ip>: Connection refused` when I run `telnet public_ip 8020`. When I run `netstat -anp | grep 8020` I get

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8020              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      18908/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38750             127.0.0.1:8020              TIME_WAIT   -
```

I have other ports listening, `telnet public_ip 50070` allows me to connect. The output for netstat on that is

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      18908/java
```

When I execute `telnet localhost 8020` I get

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

Do I need to do something to change the 127.0.0.1 in the netstat for 8020 to 0.0.0.0 like it is for the successful connection to 50070?

The output of `iptables -L -v` is

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 84481 packets, 11M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 54190 packets, 6770K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

This is a hadoop service, the config that tells it to listen on port 8020 is in core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Please post the output of IPTables -L -v If the service/application listening to 8020 needs to be accessible outside the box itself, then you probably want to change the config of the service in question to listen to 0.0.0.0

Comment: what's the downvote for?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: What is listening on port 8020?

Comment: hadoop, the port accessible through hdfs

Comment: Show us the hadoop config the causes the port to be listened on.

Comment: I changed the config to use my public ip instead of localhost and it worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message. Yes this is the same general problem but the answer is extremely general and cites the two causes as nothing listening on the port and a firewall.  I was using the correct port, the problem was I was using an incorrect alias for my server that didn't allow other servers on the network to find it. I stated in the question that I was able to connect from the remote server and that there was a service listening on that port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
</property>
```

You told it to bind to `localhost`. That's not a good idea if you want it to be accessible from other machines.