# bind recursive dns server fail to answer for specific domain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I have bind9 dns server with resursion enabled only for internetwork. It is working normally but for one particular site it fails to provide the answer

```
"ipay.com.np"
```

When i do

```
dig @mydns.server.com ipay.com.np +trace
```

it can fetch the answer. But normal dns query without other options does work

```
dig @mydns.server.com ipay.com.np 

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> @202.94.66.2 ipay.com.np
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Update:- 
now the records for domain ipay.com.np is fetched by my caching dns automagically. I havent done any thing but restarted bind server yesterday and now it works

Comment: The `+trace` option works because then dig does **not** use your own nameservers but contacts each server from the root server down the delegation path directly...

Comment: do you have some clue on why is the caching server not fetching the result for particular domain ?

Comment: *"no servers could be reached"* is as far as I know dig's interpretation of a generic [connection refused error](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)