# Can't access particular website on Windows Server, but ping works

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, ping, website

In my Windows Server hosted in AWS, I tried to access a particular site from Chrome/IE and both browsers returned - the site can't be reached/the server refused to connect. However, when I try to ping the same website from cmd it seems to work just fine. I don't use any proxy in the network setting and Chrome is set to detect network settings automatically.

So this is definitely not an IP based block from the website. My local PC and my server PC are in the same region, but different city. It works great in my local PC but in the server, it simply works via **ping**.

What are some possible reasons that might have caused this?

**Updates**
[Telnet Connection Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAgZO.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not an IP based block, but what about procotol type or port block?

*ping* sends ICMP packages to a host but when you try to open the website via Chrome you need to establish a TCP connection to a host:port. So you should check the firewall in your server, if is hosted in AWS check also the Security Group rules.
Then you can test if you are able to connect to HTTP (80) or HTTPS ports (443), for example using:

```
telnet myserver 80 
telnet myserver 443
```

instead of

```
ping myserver
```

Comment: I tried to telnet but unfortunately I can't seem to telnet any website (screenshot attached with the original question). While checking on the Firewall settings/security group, nothing should prevent me to make an outgoing connection - leading me to one question: is it easy to detect and block connections coming from AWS instance or Windows Server OS?

Answer (score 0):

It is might be that site is stopped in IIS for example. In this case ping will show response but browser won't. Check IIS settings for sites, bindings and AppPools.

Comment: Hi, it isn't my own site. I reckon that they have geo-location restriction / detected that the connection comes in from AWS connection (which they might then block). But the puzzle is I can actually ping the site all good! And the server is located in the same region as where I live and I can access it just fine in my PC, but not in the server.

Comment: The server is behind AWS firewalls and rules, so they might have a block or rule restricting it, I assume your pc is at your home As alemarmed explained, if it is a protocol block it will be blocked only from within AWS networks, not from your home/pc provider network.