# ssh connection stopped working

Tags: ssh, remote

I'm connecting to a remote server via ssh:

```
ssh user@ip
```

I normally use the wifi network but when it fails, I use a 3G modem.
I have been working this way for few months.
But now I'm unable to connect to the server.

I'm getting the following message:

```
ssh: connect to host <ip> port 22: Connection timed out
```

I had tried to access the different servers also and got the same error, other people are able to connect to the server from their computers so the problems have to be on my side.
I'm using linux mint 17.

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/q/725262/340408

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a tcp timeout. No response from the sever not even connection refuse.

As your are unable to ssh to other servers too, it look like you are being blocked for outgoing 22 port somewhere upstream.

Doing tcp traceroute for port 22 might tell you the block location.