# Configuring a port setting on Linux server

Tags: iptables, firewall, azure, port

I'm trying to allow Internet traffic to port `7778` on my server, but am unable to do it correctly. Probably making some rookie mistake here. Can you help me diagnose and solve the issue?

I simply did the following:

```
sudo iptables -A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT
```

If I do `iptables -S`, I do see the rule appended in the list, e.g.:

```
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT
```

However, if I ping this particular port from another server - `telnet example.com 7778`, I see:

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

What else can I do here? Port `80`, `443` and `22` are working correctly FYI.

---

Note: my server uses Azure infrastructure (classic VM). An extra step I took was adding an `endpoint` for port 7778 in the Azure portal. Thus this part is covered.

Comment: show us the output of `iptables - nvL INPUT`

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation: there's quite a lot of output, do you need to see everything? Is it secure if I paste it publicly here?

Comment: Do you try to telnet 127.0.0.1 7778 in your VM?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: no, so far I've tried it remotely. I just tried it from inside the VM - and got `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`. Very peculiar!

Comment: According to the error, it seems that your service is not listening.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT: would having installed `fail2ban` have anything to do with btw?

Comment: Hi, whether your port is listening? Or you don't install the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `-A` switch you have added your rule to the end of the chain. This will almost certainly have placed it after the rule that drops/blocks packets.

When iptables/netfilter is checking to see how a packet should be acted upon. the first to match wins. In your case it will likely match a line like `-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` which will cause a Connection Refused message prior to matching your allow messages.

The solution is to use insert the rule using `-I` into a suitable place in your INPUT chain.

Comment: Makes sense, although the reject rule is above the rule for port `80` and `443` as well (see edited lines in question). Should that have blocked those ports as well?

Comment: Unless, as seems likely there is an earlier rule that allows them.

Comment: Well I pasted the full list of rules in the question; just trying to understand what's what before I insert the rule with `-I` (in case something goes wrong). As you can see, I'm using nginx `fail2ban` as well.

Comment: I executed `sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7778 -j ACCEPT`, however `telnet example.com 7778` still fails. Something very weird is going on over here. Any pointers on diagnosing this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the error log, it seems that your service is not listening.

To troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, I suggested  check as the following ways:

1.Check service in your VM.

> netstat -ant|grep 7778

Please ensure the port is listening.

2. Test by using localhost IP

> telnet 127.0.0.1 7778

Based on my knowledge, if your firewall has some missing configure, you would get the following error.

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: Hmm, when I try `netstat -ant|grep 7778`, nothing results.

Comment: You could not telnet a port that is not listening. Maybe you should check why the port is not listening.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Yep, hold on, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok, please ensure you could telnet 127.0.0.1 7778

Comment: You were right, the port was indeed listening but my service was down. All fixed! Thanks for the great help. Both of you guys gave helpful answers. Since @Hanginoninquietdesperation helped me with iptables, I'm marking him as correct.