# Yum-cron fails to send email to root

Tags: email, postfix, cron, centos7

I am trying to investigate an issue on one of our CentOS 7 servers, for which `yum-cron` fails to send an email to root with the result of the operations performed.

It always give this error:

> Failed to send an email to localhost: [Errno 111] Connection refused

However, we have other servers with the same configuration, and this is the only one showing such issue.

Here is the `yum-cron.conf` content:

```
[commands]
#  What kind of update to use:
# default                            = yum upgrade
# security                           = yum --security upgrade
# security-severity:Critical         = yum --sec-severity=Critical upgrade
# minimal                            = yum --bugfix update-minimal
# minimal-security                   = yum --security update-minimal
# minimal-security-severity:Critical =  --sec-severity=Critical update-minimal
update_cmd = default

# Whether a message should be emitted when updates are available,
# were downloaded, or applied.
update_messages = yes

# Whether updates should be downloaded when they are available.
download_updates = yes

# Whether updates should be applied when they are available.  Note
# that download_updates must also be yes for the update to be applied.
apply_updates = yes

# Maximum amout of time to randomly sleep, in minutes.  The program
# will sleep for a random amount of time between 0 and random_sleep
# minutes before running.  This is useful for e.g. staggering the
# times that multiple systems will access update servers.  If
# random_sleep is 0 or negative, the program will run immediately.
# 6*60 = 360
random_sleep = 360


[emitters]
# Name to use for this system in messages that are emitted.  If
# system_name is None, the hostname will be used.
system_name = None

# How to send messages.  Valid options are stdio and email.  If
# emit_via includes stdio, messages will be sent to stdout; this is useful
# to have cron send the messages.  If emit_via includes email, this
# program will send email itself according to the configured options.
# If emit_via is None or left blank, no messages will be sent.
emit_via = email

# The width, in characters, that messages that are emitted should be
# formatted to.
output_width = 80


[email]
# The address to send email messages from.
email_from = root

# List of addresses to send messages to.
email_to = root

# Name of the host to connect to to send email messages.
email_host = localhost


[groups]
# NOTE: This only works when group_command != objects, which is now the default
# List of groups to update
group_list = None

# The types of group packages to install
group_package_types = mandatory, default

[base]
# This section overrides yum.conf

# Use this to filter Yum core messages
# -4: critical
# -3: critical+errors
# -2: critical+errors+warnings (default)
debuglevel = -2

# skip_broken = True
mdpolicy = group:main

# Uncomment to auto-import new gpg keys (dangerous)
# assumeyes = True
```

I double checked and it is identical to the config file on the other servers.

Also, all servers have `postfix` installed as mail server, which uses sendgrid as smtp relay.

Lastly, on **all** servers, sending emails to root manually through the `mail` command works without any error.

What should I check to make the cron send emails to root correctly?

EDIT:

After some testing, I noticed that on the server with the issue, there is nothing listening on TCP port 25:

```
[root@srv1 ~]# ss -tnlp | grep :25
[root@srv1 ~]#
```

while on the other server I get:

```
[root@srv2 ~]# ss -tnlp | grep :25
LISTEN 0 100 127.0.0.1:25 *:* users:(("master",pid=768,fd=13))
[root@srv2 ~]#
```

where the process with PID 768 is `/usr/libexec/postfix/master -w`.

I then checked which processes where active for the `postfix` service, and on the first server I get:

```
[root@srv1 ~]# service postfix status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  postfix.service
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-01-10 09:18:55 CET; 5min ago
  Process: 17409 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17431 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17428 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 17421 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17503 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─17503 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─17504 pickup -l -t unix -u
           └─17505 qmgr -l -t unix -u
```

while on the second one the output is:

```
[root@srv2 ~]# service postfix status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  postfix.service
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-12-28 16:34:19 CET; 1 weeks 5 days ago
 Main PID: 768 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─ 768 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─ 770 qmgr -l -t unix -u
           ├─8185 pickup -l -t unix -u
           └─9148 tlsmgr -l -t unix -u
```

So it would seem that on the first server `tlsmgr` is not started at all, however I cannot find any error in the logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found out that it was not an issue with `yum-cron` but rather with the configuration of `postfix` itself.

In fact, on the first server, the `master.cf` file was like:

```
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
[...]
```

while on the second server it was:

```
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
[...]
```

and by setting the first file as the second, that is, uncommenting the first `smtp` line and removing the `submission` line, I got it working as expected.