# Enabling SSL For GitLab Results in ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ssl, gitlab

I have had an existing GitLab installation for a few months, and I decided it was time to add a real SSL certificate (not self-signed).

Following the documentation, I change the following line:

```
external_url 'http://<domain>.com'
```

to:

```
external_url 'https://<domain>.com'
```

And uncommented the following lines:

```
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key"
```

And just to be sure, I double-checked the key files:

```
root@host:/etc/gitlab# cat /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...

root@host:/etc/gitlab# cat /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
```

Then I ran `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, and I got a successful message at the end. However, navigating to the GitLab URL, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. When I comment out all the lines above and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, everything goes back to normal on HTTP port 80.

What might cause nginx to refuse connections when I feed the configuration file two certificates and adjust the URL? Thanks!

Comment: What other relevant settings have you set in gitlab.rb?

Comment: Nothing relating to nginx or the URL. That's about all I can think qualifies as relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: Have you installed an intermediate certificate? does'nt look like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like GitLab is not listening on 443. The redirect on 80 sends you to 443 where you get Connection Refused. The config should have a `listen 443` line (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) that allows it to receive SSL requests.

Example from the page:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out that `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb/` - the file you're supposed to put your SSL settings in - did not actually configure the nginx file like it was supposed to. Manually configuring SSL in the built-in nginx bundle solved the problem!

Comment: So how exactly can this be fixed? I'm having the same issue, not sure how to proceed

Comment: Anyone else have an answer?   Followed the link  (Took forever to figure out that the config file is in /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf )   It has TWO server {} configuration sections, the first one for port 80, the 2nd one for SSL, so I configured the 2nd one, but don't know if that is good or not...  I just tried flipping which server entry was on top... we will see if that works..