# mariaDB can't connect from remote host

Tags: mariadb

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%skip_networking%';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| skip_networking | OFF   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I try

```
mysql -uroot -p -h 192.168.0.30
```

I received this

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.30' (111 "Connection refused")
```

In the file

```
 /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

I have this:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
# skip-networking
```

I hope you can help me.

local connection works.

```
sudo netstat -ntlup | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11580/mysqld
```

I see the "127.0.0.1:3306" but I don't know how can I change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](http://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/7499402

What is disabled by default is remote `root` access.  If you want to enable that, run this SQL command locally:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And then find the following line and **comment it out** in your `my.cnf` file, which usually lives on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Unix/OSX systems.  If it's a Windows system, you can find it in the MySQL installation directory, usually something like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\`   and the filename will be `my.ini`.

Change line

```
 bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
 #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

And [restart the MySQL server](https://superuser.com/questions/282115/how-to-restart-mysql) for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i could solve it by checking this aspects:

First of all, accessing your db with an account that accepts remote connections. As mentioned on other posts that account should have a % in the server name instead of a localhost.

I don't know if it is a secure practice to do this but i think it is ok to start.

[Example of phpmyadmin lay out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9tLw.png)

After that you should check the configuration files from

- */etc/mysql*
- */etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*

I had to deduce from the */etc/mysql/my.conf because it includes this lines

```
user@debian:/etc/mysql$ cat my.cnf
# The MariaDB configuration file
#
# The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following             order:
# 1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
# 2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
# 3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
# 4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
[client-server]

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

The thing is the second dir owns this files:

```
user@debian:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d$ ls
50-client.cnf  50-mysql-clients.cnf  50-mysqld_safe.cnf  50-server.cnf
```

In which logically, in the *50-server.cnf* contains the lines that are referenced in the posts but no longer in */etc/mysql/my.cnf*. 
Note: The output from this commands has been edited to clarify the answer.

Just comment the bind-address line and connect to your database from a remote terminal.

```
user@debian:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d$ cat 50-server.cnf 
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#
[server]
[mysqld]
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

After that my remote connection worked. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The process `mysqld` is listening on `127.0.0.1:3306` as shown in `netstat` output. This explains why you are getting `connection refused` error when connecting remotely. It is just accepting connections locally.

After verifying you are changing the right config file, you need to restart mysqld process.

Comment: Yes. But how can i change it? I have check all config files where I have found and there is no bind-address or skip-networking

Comment: @Koda: Did you restart your DB process after that?

Comment: yes. I have try to reboot the complete system too

Comment: If you are on a system running firewalld you've to allow the `mysql` service 
 using `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mysql  && firewall-cmd --reload` .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the location of your configuration. I don't think /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d is picked up on by mariadb.

Their documentation to address your issue (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/) suggests putting your bind-address in a my.cnf file:

```
  * /etc/my.cnf                              (*nix/BSD)
  * $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf                       (*nix/BSD) *Most Notably /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  * SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf                        (*nix/BSD)
  * DATADIR\my.ini                           (Windows)
```

I suspect you may be able to add your `bind-address` config in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.local, and that should make mariadb listen on 0.0.0.0.

Based on your netstat output, I think your extra config file is simply not being picked up.