# Temporary authentication failure 454 4.7.1 <email>: Relay access denied

Tags: iptables, postfix, smtp, squirrelmail

I can receive mail, but cannot send to outside world in Squirrelmail.

```
Message not sent. Server replied:

    Temporary authentication failure
    454 4.7.1 <email@somemail.com>: Relay access denied
```

I double checked that postfix works, i.e. able to telnet via mail.domain.com and smtp.domain.com. Dovecot works too. Seems that Squirrelmail is a suspect. Playing with configurations, not sure what could cause the problem.

Logs show this info:

```
mail.domain.com postfix/smtpd[4443]: connect from mail.domain.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
mail.domain.com postfix/smtpd[4443]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.domain.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: 454 4.7.1 <email@somemail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user@domain.com> to=<email@somemail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.domain.com>
mail.domain.com postfix/smtpd[4443]: lost connection after RCPT from mail.domain.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
mail.domain.com postfix/smtpd[4443]: disconnect from mail.domain.com[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 commands=2/3
```

netstat -plntu

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 192.168.124.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1107/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1905/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      937/master          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      3521/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1905/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      940/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      940/dovecot         
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           736/chronyd         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           722/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55024           0.0.0.0:*                           722/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 192.168.124.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           1107/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1107/dnsmasq        
udp6       0      0 :::41119                :::*                                722/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                736/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                722/avahi-daemon: r
```

Iptables are as follows:

```
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.124.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.124.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
```

iptables -L

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.124.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.124.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
```

iptables-save

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [9985:4365661]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9969:4364853]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10509:2272775]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10545:2275457]
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [78:6056]
:INPUT ACCEPT [62:5248]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1057:68220]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1057:68220]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.124.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.124.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.124.0/24 ! -d 192.168.124.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.124.0/24 ! -d 192.168.124.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.124.0/24 ! -d 192.168.124.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [9969:4364853]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10509:2272775]
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.124.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.124.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Update 15.11.2017:
This issue has been overcome by changing config in Squirrelmail. 
Run

```
/usr/share/squirrelmail/config/conf.pl
```

Go to: Server Settings -> Update IMAP Settings -> imap.domain.com
and Update SMTP Settings -> smtp.domain.com.
It used to be just localhost.

Update 14.11.2017:
Disabled firewall and was able to send mail again. However, problem with iptables remain. Also in SELinux I tried:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Update 13.11.2017
Cannot send an email on Squirrelmail after enabling firewall and opening ports 80/443, 25/143. Please, help!

ERROR:
Message not sent. Server replied:

```
Connection refused
111 Can't open SMTP stream.
```

This question comes from the following thread.
[Postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail server able to send but not receive emails](https://serverfault.com/questions/883181/postfix-dovecot-squirrelmail-server-able-to-send-but-not-receive-emails)

Comment: I see your netstat but I can't see you iptables rules. Provide your current iptables-save please.

Comment: Fedora runs `firewalld` as default. Check, `SELinux` and show more information than this.

Comment: that was the whole point. to keep firewalld on and open specific ports like 80 and 110 etc. what do you suggest now? i disabled firewalld, because i dont know if it is blocking iptables. also i tried to add line to /etc/sysconfig/iptables: -A IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT, then did service iptables save. however iptables -S | grep 25 showed nothing

Comment: In my case, none of the search fixes worked. But by looking at the mail log: `RCPT from localhost[::1]: 454 4.7.1` , the from was the key. I just added `localhost` to `mynetworks` and could send mail through Squirrelmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to send email finally by editing the Squirrelamil config file. Basically I switched from SMTP to Sendmail. In /etc/squirrelmail/config.php  change

```
$useSendmail            = true;
```

then restart apache

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

then allow Selinux to use sendmail

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1
```

I doubt that this configuration of Squirrelmail will hold long. Im definitely going to play with it. For now, not sure why SMTP didn't work, but sendmail did. Hopefully, will figure out by messing with SELinux. 
In the meantime, anyone has opinion on whether SMTP or Sendmail is the best one to use?