Postfix Temporary authentication failure 454 4.7.1
I followed https://www.unixmen.com/setup-a-local-mail-server-in-centos-7/ to setup my mail server.
Currently,my mail server can neither receive from nor send to an external email account.Postfix and Dovecot are working perfectly,and it seems I can't telnet stg.plus(MX Record to csm.hostat.cloud) but csm.hostat.cloud(A Record to the server) is working.
SquirrelMail Screenshot
Postfix main.cf
netstat -plntu
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25110           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3150/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5336/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      5207/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::25110                :::*                    LISTEN      3150/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::16823                :::*                    LISTEN      2971/v2ray          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      5336/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      5081/dovecot        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1/systemd           
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           2109/chronyd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:879             0.0.0.0:*                           2012/rpcbind        
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1/systemd           
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                2109/chronyd        
udp6       0      0 :::879                  :::*                                2012/rpcbind        

iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination     

iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Aug 17 00:14:33 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [105:5976]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [82:5528]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Aug 17 00:14:33 2024

This question actually mentioned the same error but different from mine.https://serverfault.com/questions/883344/temporary-authentication-failure-454-4-7-1-email-relay-access-denied
The writer of https://www.unixmen.com/setup-a-local-mail-server-in-centos-7/ didn't mention the SMTP and IMAP server settings.Please comment if you have any solutions.Appreciate that.
stg.plus
hostat.cloud
