# MySQL: Suddenly connection error without making any changes

Tags: linux, mysql, ubuntu-16.04, phpmyadmin

I'm running `MySQL 5.6.30 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` on `ubuntu-16.04-x86_64` and I'm using `phpMyAdmin 4.7.7`.

Sometimes, without doing anything on the Server or phpMyAdmin, I'm getting this error message on my websites:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

When trying to log in into phpMyAdmin I'm getting these four error messages:

> #2002 - No such file or directory – The server is not responding (or
>   the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

.

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

.

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

After making a `reboot` everything is working fine as normal, there are no error messages any more and I'm able to login into phpMyAdmin.

Why does it happen? Any ideas?

Comment: Last time I've tried something like this, is turned out to be as simple as a "no more disk space" :/ So next time it's occur I'll suggest you do a "`df -sh`" on your tmp drive PS: As this isn't an exact answer, I've would have added it as a comment, but not allowed to

Comment: It is likely to be a failed or failing disk on the server. Check `/var/log/messages` for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas?

- [Search](https://serverfault.com/search) is your friend.
- As per [What Causes the 'Connection Refused' message ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message), it seems likely that nothing is listening. We can deduce that MySQL has likely stopped working.
- Examine your system and mysql logs to find relevant messages and understand the issue.

I will take a wild guess and suggest that the [OOM killer](https://serverfault.com/search?q=mysql%20oom) is killing MySQL because your system is running out of memory. I could be wildly wring though, it could be [cosmic rays](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/bofhserver.pl) or disc space or something completely different.