# I can not access Http Server on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It can be so easy. But I can not it.

I run a http server on my EC2 server. And I can access it through localhost.

[image]

My Inbound rules:

[image]

And my http request with Public DNS (IPv4):

[image]

What is the missing?

Comment: May be 80 is not opened on ubuntu firewall? https://askubuntu.com/questions/646293/open-port-80-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: firewall is inactive `ubuntu@ip-172:~$ sudo ufw status =>
Status: inactive`

Comment: Is the instance in a Public Subnet? (When you SSH to it, do you connect directly from a computer on the Internet?) Could you network be blocking traffic to certain IP address ranges? (Have you tried it from different locations, eg work and home?)

Comment: Your question is already answered here https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message

Answer (score 0):

At a guess the webserver isn't listening to port 80, as you're getting `Connection Refused` in Chrome.

You can quickly test this with python:

```
 sudo python -m BaseHTTPServer 80
```

You should then be able to connect and get a 501 error back from python

NB: Don't use `SimpleHTTPServer`, you'll expose your server's filesystem to the internet

Comment: Already I have a http server that listening on 80 port. I show in the first screenshot.

Comment: Its not listening on ethernet though (as evidenced by the conn refused from chrome), its probably listening on the loopback interface.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have installed another web server and it works. But my simple server is not work. What do I need to do?