# IP to domain DNS error

Tags: ubuntu, domain, dns-zone

I have bought the domain name example.eu and have set it up from my domain registrar to use ns1.example.eu and ns2.example.eu with the server's IP 12.34.567.890. However it is not working. According to the domain registrar there is not problem with their setup.

I have installed the LEMP stack (Ubuntu 16.04).

I also tried using the freeDNS service, however it is also not working.

Also, I set up BIND9 on my server without any results.

This is my named.conf

```
zone "example.eu" {
    type master;
    file /etc/bind/external/example.eu;
    allow-transfer {
            # IPs allowed to AXFR
            12.34.567.890;
            12.34.567.890;
    };
    allow-update {
            # IPs allowed to update the zone
            12.34.567.890;
            12.34.567.890;
    };
    allow-query {
            # IPs allowed to query the zone (everyone)
            0.0.0.0/0;
    };
    notify yes;
};
```

/etc/bind/external/example.eu

```
; example.eu
$TTL 86400
example.eu.     IN  SOA ns1.example.eu. sales.example.eu. (
                2018080601      ; Serial number
                10800           ; Refresh
                3600            ; Retry
                604800          ; Expire
                86400)          ; Minimum TTL

            ; Nameserver definition
            IN  NS  ns1.example.eu.
            IN  NS  ns2.example.eu.

            ; Mail exchanger definition
            IN  MX  10  mail.example.eu.
            IN  MX  50  mail.example.eu.

; A records definition
example.eu.     IN  A   12.34.567.890
www.example.eu. IN  A   12.34.567.890
ns1.example.eu. IN  A   12.34.567.890
ns2.example.eu. IN  A   12.34.567.890
mail.example.eu.    IN  A   12.34.567.890
mail.example.eu.    IN  A   12.34.567.890
*   IN  A   12.34.567.890
```

And this is my Nginx configuration file

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 }

 server {

     listen 80;
     server_name example.eu www.example.eu;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example;
     include /var/www/example/nginx.conf.sample;

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for including your actual domain.

When I check the name servers configured by the registrar for your domain (with Whois or by checking a root server for the .EU domain):

```
dig   anthemionflowers.eu @x.dns.eu
```

I see 4 additional ones which are not controlled by you:

```
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.anthemionflowers.eu.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN  NS  ns3.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN  NS  ns4.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.anthemionflowers.eu.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.anthemionflowers.eu. 86400  IN  A   51.15.101.173
ns2.anthemionflowers.eu. 86400  IN  A   51.15.101.173
```

That seems a configuration error made at the registrar level. That should only return your actual name servers.

Additionally 51.15.101.173 is not responding to DNS queries.

```
dig ns anthemionflowers.eu @51.15.101.173

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> ns anthemionflowers.eu @51.15.101.173
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. ns1-4.afraid.org are the nameservers provided by the freeDNS service. Since the server is not responding to DNS queries, should I ask my hosting provider (Scaleway) for further assistance?

Comment: *"Since the server is not responding to DNS queries, should I ask my hosting provider (Scaleway) for further assistance?"* - Or you could start by checking [the cause of the *connection timeout* error](https://serverfault.com/q/725262/37681)

Comment: @Vasilis It is your own DNS server at 51.15.101.173 which is timing out. Is your DNS server running? Is it firewalled?

Answer (score 3):

You have created your glue records of `ns1.anthemionflowers.eu`, but your NS and SOA records are still pointing to `afraid.org`. From a linux box, if you run `dig +trace anthemionflowers.eu` you'll get:

```
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN      NS      ns2.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN      NS      ns2.anthemionflowers.eu.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN      NS      ns4.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN      NS      ns3.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN      NS      ns1.afraid.org.
anthemionflowers.eu.    86400   IN      NS      ns1.anthemionflowers.eu.
```

You should delete those entries for `afraid.org` from your NS configuration with your registrar.

---

Opining moment: It's pretty poor practice (read: very bad) to have two NS's resolving to the same IP address. It makes your DNS extremely fragile.

Also I strongly recommend not running your own DNS at all - hosted DNS is absurdly cheap and comes with guaranteed SLAs and gigantic infrastructure behind it. Azure DNS, Route 53, Google Cloud DNS - frankly pretty much anything except running it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I will keep them in mind once I solve this error. Even if I remove the afraid.org entries, which were added afterwards, It still wouldn't work. On my domain registrant, I have an A record pointing to the server's IP.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. There was an error in my named.conf file which I noticed upon running "named-checkconf" on the file.