# Why can some users connect to a DB and others can't?

Tags: database-administration, database-connection, connection-refused

I have a geospatial database that one of my users needs to connect to.

Whenever he tries to connect from his workstation he gets an invalid connection/connection refused error. He is not able to connect to it from any other workstation. There are other users who are able to connect to the DB from his workstation, including myself.

I checked Active Directory and his policies/privileges are the same as the other users who are able to connect.

We're using ESRI Arc Map 10.6 to connect to the DB.

How can I remedy this?

Edit: I don't think that the port is closed or that there is any interference from the firewall as there are users who can connect to that database from the same machine I'm having issues with. I have even gone so far as to make him a sysad (my profile/permissions) and he was still unable to connect. (I have since removed this permission)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: It may be a permission issue in the Arc Store DB.  Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: failed to connect to the database this release of the geodatabase is either invalid or out of date.

I have it working for him now temporarily. I cloned the account that could connect and assigned it to him. It's not an ideal solution.