# nginx connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream [Mastodon]

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, networking, connection-refused

I am setting up a Mastodon server on Docker on Ubuntu.

The server is up and running but when I try to access the site from a browser I get the error 502 Bad Gateway.

I have checked that ufw is permitting connections:

[image: ufw status]

And I checked that nginx is listening:

[image: netstat -tnlp]

Looking in the nginx error log I can see entries such as this one:

```
2020/07/01 06:47:59 [error] 11686#11686: *1 connect() failed (111:
Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
27.33.64.244, server: www.canberrasocial.net, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: 
http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "www.canberrasocial.net"
```

I also confirmed that Docker is up and running though I see some unusual messages which I don't understand:

[image: systemctl status docker]

I'm fairly new to linux admin so my apologies if this is a dumb question, but I'm really stumped as to how to resolve this issue. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: 27.33.64.244 is your IP address. As for your problem, please see [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/q/725262/126632).

Comment: Hi Michael. My IP address is 45.76.124.78. You can verify that by pinging the domain. In addition, it's the IP I use to ssh in to the server. That's why I mentioned the 27.33.64.244 address as being confusing for me.

Comment: 45.76.124.78 is the IP address of your vultr.com server. The other address is YOUR home address from TPG.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Sorry, I never thought to check my own home IP. I'll focus then on the connection refused. I did read the link you provided and I had previously allowed connection on the firewall with "ufw allow HTTP" and "ufw allow HTTPS" as one of the steps during the initial setup of my server. I'm a bit more hazy on the other possibility of no process listening as I thought Nginx was listening on :80 and :443 based on the netstat above?