# Socket.io error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in Azure linux server

Tags: apache-2.2, azure, javascript, socket.io

When opening [this web page](http://aspabotti1.omnia.fi:444/) I get the following errors in the debug console:

```
localhost:5005/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJKuQEf:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
index.min.js:129 Error: xhr poll error
    at u.i.onError (index.min.js:23)
    at l.<anonymous> (index.min.js:127)
    at l.r.emit (index.min.js:5)
    at l.onError (index.min.js:127)
    at index.min.js:127
```

I think it is related to index.html configuration

```
paulii@vetbot:/var/www/html$ cat index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="webchat"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.min.js"></script>
// moro you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js
<script>
  WebChat.default.init({
    selector: "#webchat",
    initPayload: "/aloitus",
    customData: {"language": "en"}, // arbitrary custom data. Stay minimal as this will be added to the socket
    socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
    socketPath: "/socket.io/",
    embedded: true,
    title: "Demo bot",
    subtitle: "Subtitle",
    params: {"storage": "session"} // can be set to "local"  or "session". details in storage section.
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**My environment**:
rasa chatbot running in docker, port 5005 opened. Apache2 web server. All running in Azure Ubuntu 18.04 server.

**More info**

```
paulii@vetbot:/var/www/html$ sudo netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29130         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1628/mdsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      851/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1153/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5005                 :::*                    LISTEN      4716/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1153/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::444                  :::*                    LISTEN      5915/apache2
```

and I get this text from index.html to website, you can try yourselves too

> // moro you can add a version tag if you need, e.g for version 0.11.5 https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat@0.11.5/lib/index.min.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: localhost is not the correct hostname! You can't access it from any other computer than the one it runs on.

Comment: Thank you Michael but this local host is used for connecting to docker where Rasa is running. I have opened port 5005 at docker for that usage

Comment: Your web browser does not run on that host!

Comment: Thank you Michael again, but think it is not the case here. I have apache webserver running and serving that index.html to public internet i.e. aspabotti1.omnia.fi:444

Comment: You missed the point again. You told the web browser to connect to a websocket server on localhost! It is not on localhost. Localhost means the same machine. So the web browser cannot connect to it because the websocket server is not on the same computer as the web browser.

Comment: Now it is working; I needed to ask IT server people to open ports on server side