# Common reasons for refused connection

Tags: http, connection, connection-refused

When you try to access a HTTP server (e.g., [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com)) and the connection is refused, what could be some common reasons at the server end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 0):

There's a firewall that is blocking port 80 or port 443? There's an access list denying the particular subnet you are coming from.