# How to run helm from a docker image

Tags: docker, helm

**UPDATE**
This is slightly different than the posted comment asking if the linked question resolves my issue.  The problem is that helm in the container is trying to connect to `localhost` which is not correct.  It should be reading my information from the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable being passed in.  Unless helm is trying to spin up a container and connect to that...which would definitely give a connection refused because that won't work.

**ORIGINAL**

We use a helm container in our CI environment to execute our helm commands and it works swimmingly.  I am trying to replicate that success running helm from a container locally and not having much luck.  I'm 99% sure it's a config issue, but I haven't been able to find any thing on the Internet specific to this situation.  Here's the snippet docker command from my script.  I've been testing with `ls` as the argument:

```
  docker run \
      -v $(pwd):/apps \
      -v "${HOME}/.kube:/root/.kube" \
      -v "${HOME}/.helm:/root/.helm" \
      -e KUBECONFIG=${HOME}/foo/kubeconfig \
      -it \
      -w "$(pwd)" \
      -ti \
      docker-dev.foo.com/bar/bat/helm helm "$@"
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Get http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

If I do a `helm ls` locally (I.e., *outside* the container), everything works just fine which is why I believe this is a config issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: Not directly.  I mean, the problem is that it's trying to connect to `localhost` and not the config specified by my `KUBECONFIG`.  But WHY it's trying to connect to `localhost` is not at all clear.

Comment: Not my area, but if you are so sure it's a config problem, maybe posting your `${HOME}/foo/kubeconfig` file would be pertinent? The docker command should also be run as the same person who owns that $HOME location unless you have set specific permissions on the file/dir.

Comment: @bshea wouldn't make a difference in this particular case as that path is the same locally as is in the container and `helm` works just fine when running locally with that `$KUBECONFIG`.