# Connection refused on port 8088 Apache Superset

Tags: iptables, port

I have an apache superset instance running on a remote server on port 8088:

`INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8088/`

When trying to connect to the server with `servername:8088` I get a connection refused error.

I set iptable rules with `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8088 -j ACCEPT`.

`iptables -L` gives:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:omniorb
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:omniorb

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:omniorb
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:omniorb
```

and `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :8088`:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8088          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1744/python3.6
```

Any help to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: The dupe will help you solve our problem, your  `servername` does not resolve to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I read through that and it doesn't. Maybe I don't understand enough of what I'm trying to do here

Comment: @user9517 okay how do I make the server do that?

Comment: make an entry in /etc/hosts for servername pointing to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @topmop75 I already did that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish the external port mapping to the superset image?

docker run -p  8080:8088 -name <<"container">> <<"image">>

here you are declaring that 8080 matches the 8088 container port