# After upgrade from MongoDB 4.x to 5.0.2 shows Connection Refused trying to connect BD from Private Network

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb, troubleshooting, ubuntu-20.04, database-connection

I have upgraded my MongoDB from 4.x to 5.0.2 into a Ubuntu 20.04 system. This server is an AWS EC2 Instance. After upgrade I can't connect my applications from other ec2 instances using the same Network (private network), but I can connect using my public ip address by mongo compass. So, I have ensured that my Mongo DB server is into a same network from other instances and it have the correct entrance into my Inbound Rules at Security Group. I have checked my /etc/mongod.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /sys/log/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Someone has had this problem or have any idea that how I can fix it?

Comment: Now I tried:
```
$ nc -zv 172.0.0.14 27017
nc: connect to 172.0.0.14 port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

```


I have no ufw enabled.

Comment: Have you checked any logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)