# my nginx server was working perfectly fine and now shows a 502 error

Tags: nginx, deployment, node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I'm deploying my project,
I had no problem until i decided to buy a domain for my digital ocean droplet
i added the records from my namecheap domain to my droplet
i was working on it then suddenly when i want access to myproject/api it's now showing **502 errors**
i'll give you all the informations so maybe you can help me with it

1 ) mongoDB atlas status : `All good` ; i even tried " npm start " to see if DB can't connect but it connects perfectly fine. I refreshed in .env the connecting string, it stills connect with no problems.

2 ) Nginx error.log shows this information i don't really understand, i guess it's the key point :
`86 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 164.92.206.160, server: _, request: "GET /api/category/cinema HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/api`

3 ) The front is perfectly showing himself on my project domain url it starts showing **502 error** when i click something using my DB/server.

4 ) i rebuilded and restarted front & back + nginx multiple times

5 ) i updated endpoints and .env variables to match with my fresh domain and it works, only the API side is breaking

6 ) nginx conf file :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

      

        root /var/www/html;


        server_name _;

        location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

I tried barely everything and it's still not working as it was used to work.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message

Answer (score 2):

As the linked thread indicated in comment, probably your upstream server isn't listening at `http://[::1]:8000`.

Note that `[::1]` is the IPv6 loopback address (like `127.0.0.1` for IPv4), so if the upstream is IPv4 only, you should explicitly write `127.0.0.1` in config file, instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, i'm real newbie, where i'm supposed to write your suggestion in my conf file ? Thanks for trying to help me tho

Comment: proxy_pass http://localhost:8000 into proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1 ? or into proxy_pass http://164.92.206.160 ? Or shall i activate Ipv6 on my digital ocean droplet and use the Ipv6 adress ?

Comment: You might get started from `127.0.0.1:8000`. If it works, then you don't really need further changes like activating IPv6 on droplet.

Comment: I get it i think so but i have no idea where i'm supposed to enter this new value ? By replacing this line ? proxy_pass localhost:8000 ? Like proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000 ?

Comment: Yes, replace `proxy_pass localhost:8000` with `proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try out the solution asap and comeback to tell you if it worked

Comment: Not working with 127.0.0.1:8000 i try with  164.92.206.160:8000 error code : ''' 25 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 164.92.206.160, server: _, request: "GET /api/category/cinema HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category/cinema", host: "164.92.206.160 '''

Comment: not working either with 164.92.206.160:8000 error code : 4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 164.92.206.160, server: _, request: "GET /api/category/cinema HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://164.92.206.160:8000/api/category/cinema", host: "164.92.206.160

Comment: @Harkayn then the information provided by you in the question body is incorrect. How exactly did you configure the upstream server? Edit the question to explain further and use `netstat` to analyze what port it listens on.

Comment: tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:http     4vg55-h01-176-133:50389   
tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:50156  104.21.29.13:http        
tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:http     4vg55-h01-176-133:50387 
tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:http     4vg55-h01-176-133:50390 
tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:http     4vg55-h01-176-133:50388 
tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:http     4vg55-h01-176-133:50391 
tcp        0      0 SEOBLOG:http     4vg55-h01-176-133:50392 
tcp6       0    736 SEOBLOG:ssh   162.243.190.66:33216    ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 SEOBLOG:ssh     162.243.190.66:33216    ESTABLISHED