# getting error with curl command in Ubuntu

Tags: firewall, virtual-machines, curl

Below I am having these issues with all my VMs. I am unable to curl from my VMS and subsequently having issues with another program. host OS is ubuntu 20.04 and the guest is Centos 7

[see error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpuYX.png)

Comment: there's nothing listening on `127.0.0.1:1234`

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)