# Local Windows machine cannot connect to another except port 80

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, port

Trying to test a dev web service endpoint.

Firewalls and Windows Defender are off on both.

From different machine

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -ComputerName 192.168.1.5 -InformationLevel Detailed
TcpTestSucceeded        : True

Test-NetConnection -Port 5178 -ComputerName 192.168.1.5 -InformationLevel Detailed
TcpTestSucceeded        : False
```

When I test on same machine

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 80 -ComputerName 192.168.1.5 -InformationLevel Detailed
TcpTestSucceeded        : True

Test-NetConnection -Port 5178 -ComputerName 192.168.1.5 -InformationLevel Detailed
TcpTestSucceeded        : False

Test-NetConnection -Port 5178 -ComputerName localhost -InformationLevel Detailed
TcpTestSucceeded        : True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: This is a SuperUser question. Are you aware that localhost does not use the network stack? You will also be required to provide more information on the firewall disablement other than "off", given how often that is done incorrectly and off isn't meaningful except to make it more murky and non-standard. Also be prepared to provide a netmon capture from both endpoints and have them correlated.

Comment: It would appear that your process/service is not bound to, and is not listening on, 192.168.1.5.

Comment: Thank you joeqwerty. That was indeed the issue. Seems so obvious after the fact.

Comment: Glad to help...