# NGINX domain conf file, how to redirect 301 and proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass, 301-redirect

I'm pretty new to nginx and I'm trying to configure a redirect from http to https and, in the same file, set as location a proxy_pass to the desired URL.

My domain.com file is this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name my.example.com;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/example.com/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/example.com/privkey.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://other.example.org:10302/some/folder/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}
```

if I run nginx -t I got sintax OK, if I reload nginx it reload w/out issues but if I point to my.domain.com I see default nginx page (in http), no redirect to https, non proxy_pass; if I point to https://my.example.com I got connection refused, if I point to https://other.example.org:10302/some/folder/ I can connect w/out any issue.

My certificate.crt is made with:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.csr -out certificate.crt
```

is it ok or I need to made it in a different way?

Anyone could point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Comment: I've "solved" https issue, there was a not defined in default conf file, set it and it works, but I still not have redirect from http to https and no proxy_pass.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In your questions please refrain from using random / made-up domain names and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions. - Also see https://serverfault.com/q/725262 with regards to the connection refused because your configuration snippet looks OK

Comment: Hi @HBruijn and thanks for your reply!
I have edited my 3D and changed with example.TLD.
Regarding connection refused, I have solved, but I still have problems both for redirect 301 from HTTP to HTTPS and proxy_pass, because it don't work; now if I point to my.example.com in HTTPS I still landing on default NGINX page, certificate is loaded correctly, but I do not landing on the https://other.example.org:10302/some/folder/

Comment: Please enable error log and access log in your vhost and provide relevant logging. Also have you linked the vhost from sites-available to sites-enabled?

Comment: Provide error and access logging

Comment: Ok, my fault!
I had enabled my my.example.com but after that I had modify it under site-available and, don't ask me why, I had lost it under site-enebled. I had redo symlink, reload nginx and it works!
Thanks to all for the support, solved!

Comment: I will add it as answer please up vote it. Was a wild guess from he hahaha been there done that myself also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the link of the vhost between sites-available and sites-enabled is there.