# curl: (28) Failed to connect to X.X.X.X port 80: Connection timed out

Tags: ubuntu, ip, curl, ubuntu-20.04

I'm getting this error:

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to X.X.X.X port 80: Connection timed out
```

When I run this:

```
curl X.X.X.X
```

I'm curling a specific IP address and it fails on both port 80 and 443.  I am able to curl other IPs/websites on ports 80 and 443 on my server.

I tested curling the problematic IP from another server and it worked just fine.  Both servers are on Ubuntu 20.04.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the 'Connection Refused' message?](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message)

Answer (score 0):

In addition with @[vidarlo](https://serverfault.com/users/435764/vidarlo)'s link, a more verbose output may be helpful with `-v` option of `curl`.